# Laravel 5 : PHPunit wont start, throws internal server error

Tags: html, phpunit, laravel-5, internal-server-error

I just wrote tests for a new controller i implemented, and wanted the run them but phpunit gives me the following error... I'm running laravel 5.2. I was wondering if any of you had an idea about where it could come from?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Martin

```
$ phpunit
PHPUnit 5.6.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
    "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Internal Server Error</title>

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;}
h1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
h2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
h3 {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;font-size:11pt}
p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;font-size:9pt;margin-top: -5px}
.version {color: gray;font-size:8pt;border-top:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
/*]]>*/
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<h2>include(DB.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory</h2>
<p>
An internal error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
Please contact the webmaster to report this problem.
</p>
<p>
Thank you.
</p>
<div class="version">
2016-10-13 13:27:21 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do your test look like and when do you get this error? Have you tried only running specific tests, for example:

```
phpunit tests/someTest.php
```

**General troubleshooting:**

Try running

```
composer dump-autoload
```

And right after:

```
composer install
```

Also, unless you have it global, setup an alias for phpunit

try the following command from project root:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

You can also add is as an alias:

```
alias phpunit="/{pathtoproject}/vendor/bin/phpunit"
```

Last but not least, you can do try in your .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Comment: I tried running test separately too but it doesnt change a thing, i feel like phpunit doesn't even get to the point of running the test.

Apparently, this error page comes from Yii ! I managed to find it by doing a search in my project directory.

I already have an alias on phpunit, i tried doing ./vendor/bin/phpunit but the result is the same.

As you can see at the top of my code block, this error happens right after i enter the "phpunit" command ! 

Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: Yii framwork? Thought you were using Laravel? Did you try dumping with composer and reinstalling?

Comment: I just got hired in this company so i didnt implement this architecture and i have no idea what the usage of Yii is in this situation. I'll try to look into it!

Comment: ( Apparently Yii is used for Role Based Access Control )

Comment: What is the reason that they use Yii for the AC system?

Comment: Because it's Role Based, now he told me that they should remove it because its pretty simple to implement yourself but at the time they had to go fast and they did some bad choices :p Startup life!

Comment: I see, interesting. Well it's not hard to created a Role Bassed AC system in Laravel, there's no need to use both frameworks for that. And if you don't feel like creating your own solution, you have a lot of packages like Spatie/laravel-permission available. Feel free to set this question as solved if you managed to get around :)

Comment: Nope, still not a clue of what the issue Is :/

Answer (score -1):

We removed Yii, made our own role-based system, and now PHPunit starts! We get another error though but nothing related to this issue, thanks for your help :)